# NgRoute is not working in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsfiddle

I'm new to angular and I'm about to write my first hello world App in jsfiddlle.
I managed to load content by using ng-include but I still have problem with using ngRoute:
I'm getting

> Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of undefined

in the following code:
**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <a href="#/firstPanel">1Panel</a>
  <a href="#/secondPanel">2Panel</a>
  <div ng-include src="'main.html'"><div>
  <div ng-view></div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="first_panel.html">
    First Panel
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="second_panel.html">
    Second Panel
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="main.html">  
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
      Main {{mainCtrl.foo}} <br/>
      <input type="text" ng-model="mainCtrl.foo"/>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

var my = {};

my.MainCtrl = function() {
  this.foo = 'foo';
}

my.SecondPanelCtrl = function() {
}

my.FirstPanelCtrl = function() {
}

var routeProvider = function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/firstPanel', {
        templateUrl: 'first_panel.html',
        controller: 'FirstPanelCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'firstPanelCtrl'
      }).
      when('/secondPanel', {
        templateUrl: 'second_panel.html',
        controller: 'SecondPanelCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'secondPanelCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/firstPanel'});
};

myApp.config(routeProvider);

// register all controllers
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', my.MainCtrl);

myApp.controller('FirstPanelCtrl', my.FirstPanelCtrl);
myApp.controller('SecondPanelCtrl', my.SecondPanelCtrl);
```

And here is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ccTd6/14/

Comment: I am seeing a lot of problems running ng in jsfiddle lately. Even simple examples are not working. You might be better of using http://plnkr.co.

Comment: Strange. I've been using jsFiddle with AngularJS quite extensively and I don't encounter any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an error in your HTML syntax that messes things up:

```
<div ng-include src="'main.html'"></div>
                                   ^
          here you missed the `/`__|
```

**Note:**
At least in Chrome that I tried that, it is the browser that gets confused and removes the `ngView` div altogether - so it is not Angular's fault in any case.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I checked it few times but missed it, new pair of eyes is always good:)